# How to determine a grid that bins the given data into a smooth histogram?

Tags: python, numpy, histogram, data-processing, binning

## Description

I have some simulation data that should be binned into a histogram (binning with `sum`).

The original data is shown in the figure below. The blue dots are the data to be binned, the red lines are the `logscale` grids that define the bin boundaries.
[image: correct grid]

When correct number of bins (50) is used, the result binned histogram is a smooth curve.
[image: correct histogram]

However, if I used an incorrect grid size, for example, 58, the result becomes oscillatory
[image: incorrect histogram]

To understand the reason, look at the incorrect grid below: seems that the grid may split some periodic data in a wrong period, causing the swinging assignment of the data points and the oscillatory data.
[image: incorrect grid]

## Question

Currently, I find the optimal grid by trial and error. I wonder whether there is a easy way to find the grid that will bin the data into a smooth curve (assume always exists) ?

## Sample data

The sample data `N` is uploaded in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/wuyuanyi135/55b76b6d6d7ada9c44d28852a3016714). The first column is `Size`, and the second column is `Count`.

I have created a sample [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wJ4JqfUsfKYwFtVJ_Zo7YLxuG_JZhYba?usp=sharing) to reproduce the plot.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind including your `ax` definition so we can reproduce your plot?

Comment: @orlp Thanks! I have created a colab notebook for reproducing the plots. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wJ4JqfUsfKYwFtVJ_Zo7YLxuG_JZhYba?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still 'trial and error', but at least programmatically. I assume we only want to find out the number of bins.

Let's check up to a certain amount of bins for the best one. We'll define the best one as the one that minimizes the mean of the absolute differences of the logs of your 'counts', putting a huge penalty on a positive difference (representing a jump in the graph).

```
def judge_grid(N, grid, pos_penalty=1e5):
    stat, bin_edges, _ = binned_statistic(N[:, 0],  N[:, 1], statistic="sum", bins=grid)
    logcounts = np.log(stat) - np.log(bin_edges[1:] - bin_edges[:-1])
    d = np.diff(logcounts)
    # Huge penalty for positive difference.
    ad = np.where(d > 0, d * pos_penalty, -d)
    return np.mean(ad)

lo = np.log10(1e-5)
hi = np.log10(1.0)
min_bins = 10
max_bins = 80
best_num_bins = min(range(min_bins, 1+max_bins),
                    key=lambda b: judge_grid(N, np.logspace(lo, hi, b)))
print(best_num_bins)
```

For your example this returns 50.

Comment: Thanks @orlp! I did find many histogram bin width optimization with iterative search method. Let me test if it works for all my use cases.

Comment: @YuanyiWu I assume that means it worked for all your test cases? :)

Comment: Yes. I think this discrete trial-and-error works because the histogram is dominated by the largest point in each bin, which are kind of evenly distributed. By tuning the edges, as long as those dominant points are evenly distributed on each bin, the histogram will look fine. This dominant-point assumption is not always true in some of my cases. I think the kernel density estimation should be the way to go in those cases.